# How to do edge detection in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, mathematical-optimization, image-processing, image

I have some pictures of water level and I want to do edge detection, I used the following command, but this command is vertical edge detection and I want horizontal edge detection and water level. Thank you for your guidance.

use three image: full, medium, empty

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ImageLines will be troublesome on this processing especially for the "empty" image where many horizontal lines can be found and ranked nearly equivalently. I suggest attempting to determine the level using the colorshift that is very evident in the "medium" image.

```
data = ImageData[img2];
Dimensions[data]
Total[data[[All, -20 ;;, 3]]\[Transpose]] // ListPlot
```

The transition is clearly at ~780 pixels which can be 205 mm?
[image]

For the "empty" image

```
data = ImageData[img3];
Dimensions[data]
Total[data[[All, -20 ;;, 3]]\[Transpose]] // ListPlot
```

Essentially no transition is observed.

[image]

For the "full" image processing is more channeling due to the reflections off of the fluid surface. A polarizer and controlled lighting may help in this case. Otherwise one may consider the first "transition" to be the level.

```
data = ImageData[img1];
Dimensions[data]
Total[data[[All, -20 ;;, 3]]\[Transpose]] // ListPlot
```

Transition at 80 pixels = ~472 mm?
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I want to import these images into the model, so I need to make changes to the images.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to use the new "empty" image**

[image]

I would start by converting images to greyscale:

```
greyimgs = Table[ColorConvert[i, "Grayscale"], {i, imgs}]
```

[image]

Then taking strips from the right-hand side, to avoid the ruler:

```
strips = Table[d = ImageDimensions[i]; 
  ImageTake[i, {1, d[[2]]}, {-50, d[[1]]}], {i, greyimgs}]
```

[image]

Binarize, using a threshold a bit lower than the average of the first row of pixels:

```
binstrips = 
 Table[abovewatergrey = Mean[ImageData[i][[1]]]; 
  Binarize[i, abovewatergrey - .2], {i, strips}]
```

[image]

Find edges in the binarized images:

```
edges = Table[EdgeDetect[i, 50], {i, binstrips}]
```

[image]

Get column-averaged line profiles from the edge detection (reversing to account for coordinate system of images)

```
profiles = Table[Reverse[Mean /@ ImageData[i] // N], {i, edges}];

ListLinePlot[profiles, PlotLegends -> {"Full", "Medium", "Empty"}]
```

[image]

Find the maximum of the profiles (used `Mean` in case there is not a unique maximium):

```
maxpos = 
 Flatten@Table[Round[Mean[Position[p, Max[p]]]], {p, profiles}]
```

> {912, 231, 78}

```
Table[HighlightImage[
  imgs[[n]], {Thick, 
   Line[{{0, maxpos[[n]]}, {ImageDimensions[imgs[[n]]][[1]], 
      maxpos[[n]]}}]}], {n, Length[imgs]}]
```

[image]

With adjustments to optimize the "empty", the "full" no longer looks correct.

**Here is another possible method:**

With exaggerated contrast adjustment:

```
strips2 = 
 Table[d = ImageDimensions[i]; 
  ImageAdjust[
   ImageTake[i, {1, d[[2]]}, {-50, d[[1]]}], {.5, 0, 1}, {Automatic, 
    Automatic}], {i, greyimgs}]
```

[image]

This is what the column-averaged profiles look like:

```
stripprofiles = (Mean /@ ImageData[#]) & /@ strips2;
ListLinePlot[stripprofiles]
```

[image]

To see where the profiles first dip precipitously, get a rolling difference between moving averages:

```
moving = Table[m = MovingAverage[p, 5];
   Table[m[[n - 1]] - m[[n]], {n, 2, Length[m]}]
   , {p, stripprofiles}];

ListLinePlot[moving, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Find the first peak (sensitive to adjustment of the threshold value (0.005 here))

```
firstpeaks = 
 First[Flatten[Position[PeakDetect[#, 0, 0, .005], 1]]] & /@ moving
```

> {82, 762, 1128}

```
Table[
 dim = ImageDimensions[imgs[[n]]];
 HighlightImage[
  imgs[[n]], {Thick, 
   Line[{{0, dim[[2]] - firstpeaks[[n]]}, {dim[[1]], 
      dim[[2]] - firstpeaks[[n]]}}]}], {n, Length[imgs]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the image related to the empty one is recognized as an error, if it can be improved, it will be better

Comment: @Erfan do you mean that the empty one should have no water line at all?

Comment: The line should be placed very low because it is the measuring standard of that line

Comment: Empty's picture was updated

Comment: @Erfan I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you for your help and guidance, MelaGo, it's better now